# MATLAB: implay with imcontrast

Tags: image, matlab, contrast

How can I change `implay` images contrast with `imcontrast` function? Is it possible to use this function? If it is not possible, what is your suggestion to change the contrast?

Comment: Have you tried it? Yes, you can, I guess.

Comment: I tried but i didn't work.  
h=implay(im), imcontrast(h); I am using imadjust right now but I prefer to use it with imcontrast if it is possible

Comment: You need to first use imcrontast, and then implay.

Comment: "IMCONTRAST expects a current figure containing an image." it gives this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contrast of the image can be changed manually by the way I described in the link:
[MATLAB: implay function Changing Options with Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071325/matlab-implay-function-changing-options-with-code)