# MATLAB: implay function Changing Options with Code

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I'm trying to change some implay options before opening the figure. The options I want to change are `"Maintain Fit to window"` and "range for image pixel intensities" which is at `Tools >Colormap` . The answer [Matlab - implay's default size window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521681/matlab-implays-default-size-window) is very helpful for beginning. However I am very new at GUI environment in MATLAB. After following the site's instructions, the code is below shows the colormap menu object.

```
close all force
implay(zeros(100,100,100))
whole_objs = findall(0);
whole_objs (end-49)
```

However I don't know which parameters I should change or how to change. How can I change them and which parameters I should change? In addition to this,any reference for understanding to GUI in MATLAB would be appreciated.

Comment: What options are you trying to change?

Comment: For example , I want to change the current situation "Maintain Fit to Window" to on using code. In addition to this, I want to change minimum and maximum value of the image pixel intesities by program instead of using GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can change simply by corresponding code:

```
h = implay(zeros(100,100,100)); % get object of the figure
h.Visual.ColorMap.Map = winter; % set the desired colormap
```

Answer (score 1):

To also enable the "Maintain Fit to window" in your script you can use the following code. This is a similar approach as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521681/matlab-implays-default-size-window). There might be a more elegant solution, but this works for me on Matlab 2020b.

```
% From answer by toygan kılıç
h = implay(zeros(100,100,100)); % get object of the figure
h.Visual.ColorMap.Map = winter; % set the desired colormap
% To enable "Maintain Fit to window"
toolMenu = findall(0,'tag','uimgr.uimenugroup_Tools'); % get the tools menu object from implay
set(toolMenu(1).Children(1),'Checked', 'on'); % check the "Maintain Fit to window" in the tools menu (just happens to be the first child)
fcnHandle = toolMenu(1).Children(1).MenuSelectedFcn; % get the function handle to the callback for the "Maintain Fit to window"
fcnHandle(); % Run the callback function for "Maintain Fit to window"
```